Escaping multiple arguments to a command in a single environment variable
I have a shell script that runs ansible that can take an argument encapsulated in a system environment variable ANSIBLE_ARGS.  For the sake of argument I cannot alter the shell script to use the positional arguments.  All arguments must be taken from the environment variable.
The script run something similar to:
ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local "${ANSIBLE_ARGS}" myplaybook.yaml

When Ansible args contains a simple argument like -vvvvv it works well. however when i feed it a more complex argument like -e {"key":"a value"} or -vvvvv -e {"key":"a value"} it does not work.
Here is my simple test to replicate the problem
--- test.sh ---
#!/bin/sh
ansible -i localhost, -c local "{ANSIBLE_ARGS}" all -m debug -a "var=key"
--- end test.sh ---

$ ANSIBLE_ARGS="-e {\"key\":\"a value\"}" ./test.sh 
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "key": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
------------------
$ ANSIBLE_ARGS="-v -e {\"key\":\"a value\"}" ./test.sh 
usage: ansible [-h] [--version] [-v] .....sic....
ansible: error: unrecognized arguments: - -e {"key":"a value"}
------------------
$ ANSIBLE_ARGS="-e={\"key\":\"a value\"} -v" ./test.sh 
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse localhost, with host_list plugin: We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: Extra data: line 1 column
 ......sic....
The error appears to be in '<string>': line 1, column 19, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
------------------
$ ANSIBLE_ARGS="-e={\"key\":\"a value\"} -e={\"foo\":1}" ./test.sh 
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse localhost, with host_list plugin: We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: Extra data: line 1 column
.... sic ....
The error appears to be in '<string>': line 1, column 19, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.


How can I get the application to properly interpret the command arguments passed from the environment variable?

"All arguments must be taken from the environment variable" -- how unfortunate.  Packing multiple arguments into a single variable is an antipattern.  The kind of issue you're asking about is one of the primary reasons for that.

You can't do anything without altering the script, and even then you would need to use eval to ensure that the command that results from the parameter expansion gets parsed as needed. But since that opens up a world of additional problems, you would be better off altering the script to accept command-line arguments.


I have a shell script that runs ansible that can take an argument encapsulated in a system environment variable ANSIBLE_ARGS.

Packing multiple arguments into a single string is a poor practice, giving rise to a couple of different categories of issues.  The best practice in a shell that provides arrays, such as Bash, is to use an array.  You cannot store arrays in the environment, however.

The script run something similar to:
ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local "${ANSIBLE_ARGS}" myplaybook.yaml

When Ansible args contains a simple argument like -vvvvv it works
well. however when i feed it a more complex argument like -e {"key":"a
value"} or -vvvvv -e {"key":"a value"} it does not work.

Of course not.  In the "more complex" cases, you are trying to convey multiple arguments to the ansible-playbook command, but when you expand $ANSIBLE_ARGS inside (double) quotes, the result is not subject to word splitting.  You get the whole value of the variable as a single argument.
If you're truly committed to passing multiple arguments in a single environment variable then you'll need to arrange somehow to split the value into its constituent elements before running the command.  The quick and dirty way to do that would be to expand the value unquoted:
ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local ${ANSIBLE_ARGS} myplaybook.yaml

The issue with that is that the result of expanding the variable will be subject to word splitting, and pathname expansion.  That approach relies on the word splitting for separating the result into multiple arguments, but you are liable sometimes to get splitting at places where you didn't want it, too, plus the pathname expansions will be an issue under some circumstances.

How can I get the application to properly interpret the command arguments passed from the environment variable?

To do that reliably for arbitrary arguments is very difficult.  You would be best off passing the arguments to the host script on the command line, instead.
To do it via a single environment variable, you need a way to encode the value of the environment variable in such a way that you can (just) split the value into array elements in your script.  Having performed such a split into array-valued variable ARGS_ARRAY, you would use this variation on your command:
ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local "${ARGS_ARRAY[@]}" myplaybook.yaml

(That's also how you would do it with command-line arguments.  Using arguments just makes it easier to build the needed array.  Possibly as easy as just using "$@", which can work even in a shell that doesn't have arrays.)
